# Cell balancing of two batteries connected each at the output of parallel converters

Tags: microcontroller, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, charger, cell-balancing

I am developing a scalable energy storage application where I connect bidirectional dc dc converters in parallel and battery is connected at output of each converter. I am uploading a block diagram to understand the project.
I had a doubt do I need to deploy cell balancing for this?
[image: scalable energy storage]
Two batteries 12V lead acid and 12V lithium polymer

Comment: you should always consider the cost of reduced lifespan/ increased maintenace  if you don't use BMS reusable boards

Comment: Ok so with the BMS boards connected to batteries I can charge them seprately using converters. So, how can I deploy BMS to batteries as there is no link between two batteries. They are the loads of different converters

Comment: Current sharing requires sensing and control

Comment: yes I am planning to use a Microcontroller for this application where I use current amplifiers. Do I still require BMS?

Answer (score 1):

So you have two batteries connected to each of the converters (lead-acid and LiPo) or does each converter shares a LiPo and a Lead-Acid in parallel?

Assuming you have two parallel LiPos at one converter stage and you think about balancing them, then I would start searching for information in the LiPo datasheet or some from the manufacturer producing these batteries because they probably have already a BMS (battery management system) integrated if they are rated as 12 V LiPos because a single LiPo cell has a nominal voltage of 3.7 V which means it will be a 4S cell (4 series).

Lithium batteries should always be balanced! If you find out that there is no BMS integrated in your LiPo batteries I would buy a suitable BMS and think about how to charge them safely with your bidirectional DC-DC converter.

Comment: Only 1 battery is connected to each converter as shown in the figure. It is shown two Bidirectional converters in parallel and battery at each converter output i.e., converter 1 output connected to Lithium polymer and converter 2 to lead acid.

Comment: I am using Red LiPo 2200-14.8V the link as follows: https://www.conrad.de/de/p/red-power-modellbau-akkupack-lipo-14-8-v-2200-mah-zellen-zahl-4-25-c-softcase-offene-kabelenden-1533847.html     lead acid 12V 1200 link:  https://www.conrad.de/de/p/kung-long-bleiakku-wp1-2-12-vds-12v-lead-acid-802295207.html

Comment: Okay got it right this time! 
The Lead-Acid battery doesn't need balancing. 
For the LiPo battery instead you should use the balancing connector to balance the individual cells - in your case 4 series cells, to get the maximum performance (charge cycles). If you don't balance them, they will slowly run out of phase, which then leads to different heat generation and different internal resistance and so on which puts more stress on the remaining cells. This cycle repeats and repeats until the pack will fail completely. Do you already have a strategy how to charge the LiPo with the DC/DC?

Comment: yes I am charging the batteries using bidirectional buck boost converter. So, we dnt need any balancing for lead acid but for lithium we should use balancing connector.

Comment: Yes that's right. It will also work without balancing but I would recommend to use the balance connector. :)

Comment: thanks. Had one doubt but not about cell balancing. If we connect two converter modules in parallel. Can we use Microcontroller to control the voltages. Of course we use some communication technologies like Master slave among converters. But the control of output voltage can be done by using MCU

Comment: Do you have any information regarding the mixing of different of batteries. Can you please share me.